# How do i save logs in php

Tags: php

How do i save logs in PHP? Is there any "magical" function available in php for doing so, or any library? Or should i have to `fopen` file everytime and dump in it? I want to save my logs in text file.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I just want the print_r data. something for that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote a simple class to do this. Maybe you'll find it useful.

```
class Log
  {
  public function __construct($log_name,$page_name)
    {
    if(!file_exists('/your/directory/'.$log_name)){ $log_name='a_default_log.log'; }
    $this->log_name=$log_name;

    $this->app_id=uniqid();//give each process a unique ID for differentiation
    $this->page_name=$page_name;

    $this->log_file='/your/directory/'.$this->log_name;
    $this->log=fopen($this->log_file,'a');
    }
  public function log_msg($msg)
    {//the action
    $log_line=join(' : ', array( date(DATE_RFC822), $this->page_name, $this->app_id, $msg ) );
    fwrite($this->log, $log_line."\n");
    }
  function __destruct()
    {//makes sure to close the file and write lines when the process ends.
    $this->log_msg("Closing log");
    fclose($this->log);
    }
  }

 $log=new Log('file_name','my_php_page');
 $log->log_msg('fizzy soda : 45 bubbles remaining per cubic centimeter');
```

Comment: Thanks Alex JL, but this sounds new to me `$this->app_id=self::real_unique_string()`. How will process id be useful for logs? How can the process id help me later when i view the logs?

Comment: I use process ID to keep where the line is coming from straight. It will be unique per page with the log, so say you have 5 people accessing your page at once - there will be just a flood of lines in the log. The ID it helps you know which lines came from the same process. You could always take that out if you don't need it.

Comment: This seems to be an extremely complicated version of PHP's `error_log($msg, 3, $log_name);`

Comment: @R. Bemrose   This just wraps fopen and fclose with some conveniences... I don't see how it could be seen as 'extremely complicated'.

Comment: Ok Thank Alex JL. Now i understood.

Comment: @R. Bemrose It's not complicated at all. The only thing i didn't understand till now is it the second parameter passed to hash function(`microtime(1).(time()/147))`).

Comment: @Alex JL:  OK, let me rephrase that.  This seems to be an **completely unneccessary** reimplementation of PHP's built-in `error_log($msg, 3, $log_name)` function, or just using php.ini's `error_log` ini setting to send the default error handler to a file and using `error_log($msg)`.

Comment: @R. Bemrose No, that's not true. It provides additional convenience like a> checking that the log file exists and providing a default (probably it should check that it's writable, actually) b> automatically adding a process ID, page name, date and newline after your message.  I could have used error_log instead of fopen/fwrite/fclose, but it seems rather unsemantic if you're not logging errors. I'd probably wrap error_log like this to provide the aforementioned features either way.

Comment: @Nitesh Panchal Honestly, the real_unique_id function is rather superfluous... that part could be replaced with simply uniqid(). That came from some other code I have, actually. I've edited it to make it simpler.

Answer (score 11):

If you do not want to use an own implementation or just do fopen-stuff you cyn use the built in function `error_log('string to log');` . This will write the desired string into the error log of your server software.

Comment: PHP allows you to configure what the default logger is using the `error_log` php.ini setting: http://php.net/error-log

Answer (score 6):

If you're not into using the PHP Error Handling Functions (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.errorfunc.php) that the other replies have mentioned, here is a deadly simple Logger class that I've used before. Standard warnings apply, as I have not used it in a high risk application or on a heavily trafficked site (though it should be fine).

```
<?
class Logger
{
  private static function addEntry($str)
  {
    $handle = fopen('./services.log', 'a');
    fwrite($handle, sprintf("%s %s\n", date('c'), $str));
    fclose($handle);
  }

  public static function warn($str)
  {
    self::addEntry("WARNING $str");
  }

  public static function info($str)
  {
    self::addEntry("INFO $str");
  }

  public static function debug($str)
  {
    self::addEntry("DEBUG $str");
  }
}
?>
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
<?php
require('Logger.php');
Logger::debug('test');
Logger::warn('bwah');
Logger::info('omg');
?>
```

Very simple to add more functions (like `Logger::error()`), store the file handler so you don't have to keep re-opening it every time you want to log something (ie., store the `$handle` variable in a private static class scope variable, and have `addEntry()` check to see if it's set whenever it's run and run `fopen()` if it isn't), or change the format of how you're logging.

Cheers.

Comment: Glad you like it, and thanks for the vote. And yes, this is a text book example of when to use static. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

All depends what you're trying to log. By default you will have an error_log already which is essentially a plain text file. If you're talking about logging events within your code for debugging or tracking activity within a script then you will need to write your own log handler for this but this is very simple. As another poster says you can push content to the error log using the error_log() function but this would make for some very unmanageable log files imv.

Answer (score 4):

The last answer is from 2010 so it needs a breath of fresh air. I'm sharing with you my php class that I use in my programs.
I took similar approach to `@Sam-Bisbee`'s answer above, so it's easy to add new functionalities and functions, but I also made it more flexible to use in different programs/scripts.

I put my class in `Logg.php` file, you can do it as well.

### My class

```
<?php
class Logg
{
    public static $fileName = 'new_log';
    public static $filePath = '/';
    public static $fileType = '.log';
    
    public static function addInfo($logMsg, $fName = null, $fPath = null)
    {
        $fName = $fName ?: self::$fileName;
        $fPath = $fPath ?: self::$filePath;
        self::addData($logMsg, $fName, $fPath, ' |  INFO   |');
    }
    
    public static function addWarn($logMsg, $fName = null, $fPath = null)
    {
        $fName = $fName ?: self::$fileName;
        $fPath = $fPath ?: self::$filePath;
        self::addData($logMsg, $fName, $fPath, ' | WARNING |');
    }
    
    public static function addErr($logMsg, $fName = null, $fPath = null)
    {
        $fName = $fName ?: self::$fileName;
        $fPath = $fPath ?: self::$filePath;
        self::addData($logMsg, $fName, $fPath, ' |  ERROR  |');
    }
    
    public static function addConf($logMsg, $fName = null, $fPath = null)
    {
        $fName = $fName ?: self::$fileName;
        $fPath = $fPath ?: self::$filePath;
        self::addData($logMsg, $fName, $fPath, ' | CONFIG  |');
    }
    
    private static function addData($logMsg, $fName, $fPath, $type)
    {
        $handle = fopen($fPath . $fName . self::$fileType, 'a');
        
        if (gettype($logMsg) == 'array') {
            if (count($logMsg)%2 == 0) {
                $logText = '';
                for ($i = 0; $i < count($logMsg); $i+=2) {
                    $logText .= str_pad($logMsg[$i], $logMsg[$i+1], " ", STR_PAD_BOTH).'|';
                }
                fwrite($handle, sprintf("| %s%s", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $type.$logText.PHP_EOL));
            } else {
                throw new Exception('Wrong arguments for Array-type log.');
            }
        } else {
            fwrite($handle, sprintf("| %s%s", date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), $type.' '.$logMsg.PHP_EOL));
        }
        
        fclose($handle);
    }
    
    public static function addLine($lines = 1, $fName = null, $fPath = null)
    {
        $fName = $fName ?: self::$fileName;
        $fPath = $fPath ?: self::$filePath;
        $handle = fopen($fPath . $fName . self::$fileType, 'a');
        fwrite($handle, str_repeat(PHP_EOL, $lines));
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
?>
```

### Usage examples

**Including class - specifying logs file name and path:**

```
<?php 
require '/Logg.php';

//specifying logs file name and path - best do this right after include
Logg::$fileName = 'ExampleName_'.date("Y_m_d");             //if not specified, default value = 'new_log'
Logg::$filePath = 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/public_html/logs/';   //if not specified, default value = '/'
```

You can change this values once again later on in your program if you want to.

**Simple usage:**

```
//Logging simple messages
Logg::addInfo("FooBar");            //sample information log message
Logg::addWarn("Sample warning");    //sample warning log message
Logg::addErr ("Sample error");      //sample error log message
Logg::addConf("Sample config log"); //sample config change log message

//Adding empty lines
Logg::addLine();                            //adds empty line
Logg::addInfo("Log after empty line");      //some log
Logg::addLine(3);                           //adds 3 lines instead of one
Logg::addInfo("Log after 3 empty lines");   //some log
```

**You can also use an `Array` (recommended)** instead of `String` as your "Log Message", like on examples below. It will make your log messages formatted to the specified length in order to make them more readable:

```
Logg::addLine();
Logg::addInfo(['Goo', 5]);          //logs 'Goo' as char of length 5
Logg::addInfo(['', 10, 'Goo', 5]);  //logs empty space of length 10 and a 'Goo' of length 5 after that
Logg::addInfo(['Foo',       10 , 'Bar', 5, 'Sample message with some length formatted to 75 chars',              75]); //more examples
Logg::addInfo(['FooBar',    10 , 'Baz', 5, 'Another sample message with different length formatted to 75 chars', 75]);
Logg::addLine();
Logg::addInfo(['Different message of length 65 - trying to format it to length 50', 50]);   //in this case the message will keep it initial length so we wont be loosing any of the information we are logging
```

Execution of the code above, created a file **"ExampleName_2021_08_31.log"** in the specified file path with content:

```
| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   | FooBar
| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 | WARNING | Sample warning
| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  ERROR  | Sample error
| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 | CONFIG  | Sample config log

| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   | Log after empty line



| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   | Log after 3 empty lines

| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   | Goo |
| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   |          | Goo |
| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   |   Foo    | Bar |           Sample message with some length formatted to 75 chars           |
| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   |  FooBar  | Baz |    Another sample message with different length formatted to 75 chars     |

| 2021-08-31 11:28:52 |  INFO   |Different message of length 65 - trying to format it to length 50|
```

### Changing file type

You can change to different file types by changing the **`$fileType`** property of my *Logg* class. The default file type is **".log"**.

For example:

```
//changing file type, can be put after class include
Logg::$fileType = ".txt";

//logging some example messages
Logg::addInfo("Log message now in .txt file");
Logg::addWarn("Everything will be saved to this file from now on!");
```

Now the **"ExampleName_2021_08_31.txt"** file was created with content:

```
| 2021-08-31 09:35:20 |  INFO   | Log message now in .txt file
| 2021-08-31 09:35:20 | WARNING | Everything will be saved to this file from now on!
```

### Additional function parameters

Every public "add" function has two additional parameters - **file name** and **file path**. Specifying this parameters will temporarily override the `Logg::$fileName` and `Logg::$filePath` class variables values specified earlier.
It can be usefull if you want to log some information into file with different name or file in different path, but you don't want to change the file path or file name for every log used in your program.

**Usage:**

```
//Additional parameters
Logg::addErr("New error log");                                                          //no additional parameters - uses filename and path from "Logg::$fileName" and "Logg::$filePath"
Logg::addErr("New error log in different file", "<file name>");                         //one additional parameter - uses provided filename instead of "Logg::$fileName"
Logg::addErr("New error log in different file and path", '<file name>', '<file path>'); //two additional parameters - uses provided filename and path instead of "Logg::$fileName" and "Logg::$filePath"
```

**Example:**

```
//this:
{
    //logging information to different file in different path
    Logg::addInfo(['Some info', 15], 'AnotherFileName', '/some/different/path/');
}
//is equal to this:
{
    //changing filename and path
    Logg::$fileName = 'AnotherFileName';
    Logg::$filePath = '/some/different/path/';

    //logging information
    Logg::addInfo(['Some info', 15]);

    //changing filename and path back to its original values
    Logg::$fileName = 'ExampleName_'.date("Y_m_d");
    Logg::$filePath = 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/public_html/logs/';
}
```

I'm waiting for your comments and suggestions.
Have a good day.